# QR code generation in Java using ZXing ("Zebra Crossing") API

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

The below code generate QR code successfully.

The height and width of the QR code vary based on the input **qrCodeData** we given.

Fox example if **qrCodeData=Hello World!** then height and width of generated QR code is low. If **qrCodeData=A mobile phone is a portable telephone that can make and receive calls over a radio frequency link while the user is moving within a telephone service area. The radio frequency link establishes a connection to the switching systems of a mobile phone operator, which provides access to the public switched telephone network (PSTN)** then height and width of generated QR code is larger.

Attached sample QR codes.
[image: for less data]  [image: for large data]

I want to generate QR code with same height and width irrespective to the data given in **qrCodeData**. Some one advise me.
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.javapapers.java;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel;

public class QRCode {

public static void main(String[] args) throws WriterException, IOException,
        NotFoundException {
String qrCodeData = "Hello World!";
String filePath = "QRCode.png";
String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
Map<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new                                                                      HashMap<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

    createQRCode(qrCodeData, filePath, charset, hintMap, 200, 200);
    System.out.println("QR Code image created successfully!");

    System.out.println("Data read from QR Code: "
            + readQRCode(filePath, charset, hintMap));

}

public static void createQRCode(String qrCodeData, String filePath,
        String charset, Map hintMap, int qrCodeheight, int qrCodewidth)
        throws WriterException, IOException {
    BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
            new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, qrCodewidth, qrCodeheight, hintMap);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath
            .lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
}

public static String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
            new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                    ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath)))));
    Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap,
            hintMap);
    return qrCodeResult.getText();
}
}
```

Comment: ZXing will not be able to encrypt if there is not enough space. Did you try to give you `ImageView` (in which you display the QR Code) a fixed size in DP (i.e. not using `warp_content`) ? The bitmap generated will be larger but it will be scaled down to fit your container. However, ensure the reader is still able to read the scaled down QR Code ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply mithrop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images (to be more precisely: the pixel parts of the images) have different sizes,
because there is a white margin around it.
By default this margin, the so-called [QR code quiet zone](https://qrworld.wordpress.com/category/qr-code-quiet-zone/), has a width of 4.
Hence, to get rid of the [margin](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType.html#MARGIN) you can set it to 0.
Modify your `main` method like this:

```
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object>();
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0);
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

createQRCode(qrCodeData, filePath, charset, hintMap, 200, 200);
```

Then the resulting images have no margin and the pixel parts have same size.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Now i get the QR with same height and width irrespective to the data.